# What is the largest world map anyone has created in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the largest world map that anyone has created from exploring? Is there a maximum size?

I'm curious, because I'm generating a map using [Tectonicus](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Programs_and_Editors/Tectonicus) for a single-player world where I have explored quite a bit and right now java.exe is using over 9.5GB of RAM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MineCraftWiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_Overworld#Sizes):

> In practice, technical reasons (the limits of 32-bit math) force the maximum map size, including the Far Lands, to be around 9.3 million times the surface area of Earth

Basically, Minecraft has the capability to create a map bigger than any HDD could hold.

Now, the largest map I've seen in existence is a 23GB map someone generated based off of World of Warcraft map files, but I don't know of a definitive "largest map".

Comment: Thanks, after a few links past that one reading about the Far Lands, I've discovered this: http://www.farlandsorbust.com/ 
He's been walking west for charity.